# Leg of my model deforms when i parent rig with automatic weights

Tags: rigging, armature

When i parent my rig to my model this happens -
[image]

This only happens to one of the legs even though both of the legs are the same.
How can i fix this?

Comment: Change the pole angle on the IK constraint for the affected leg.  Probably, to -90.

Comment: thank you. It worked!